# Static UITableView with custom row heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I'm trying to create **detail view controller** as a list of information and I think it would be nice and clean to present this with a static `UITableView`. But after that it came to my mind that on some level it might be difficult, so please resolve my doubts!

Every `UITableViewCell` has different style (some are **custom**, some are **basic** and few are **right-detailed** etc.).
What is more, content size of each cell may vary as I have long names put inside labels so they use autolayout to fit.

There is no problem when I have the same cells repeating but with different tex inside `UILabel`s. In that case I use a simple:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.prototypeCell) {
        self.prototypeCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ActivityCell"];
    }

    [self fetchedResultsController:[self fetchedResultsController] configureCell:self.prototypeCell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGSize size = [self.prototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

    return size.height;
}
```

---

I don't know how to deal with `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. I can give an identifier to each cell, call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and make a big switch or if statement, but is it right? The same problem occurs while I think of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and populating those `UITableViewCells`. With those testing statements this code won't be pretty and readable.

Any ideas on that case?

Comment: what is your main problem, specify that? Do you want to change the height of every cells?

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi I use autolayout to fit the content of each cell (some of them have really long strings inside labels). In that case I need to calculate height for each but they arne't using the same pattern (some are basic, some are righ detailed etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In the delegate function of the table view named heightForRowAtIndexPath try to calculate the height for each row and then return it.

```
//return height for row
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if(tableView==tblLanguage)
        {
            //Here calculate the dynamic height according to songs count for specific language

                return (([[arrSongListForSpecificLanguage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] count]*40)+40);

        }
        return 40.0;
    }
```

Comment: I've made edit to my question so please read it. Your solution is fine but for `UITableViewCell`s which have the same layout. In my case the have different layout.